# Using Require Within Define in RequireJS

Tags: javascript, dojo, requirejs, js-amd

Is it possible to use require within a define block?

I am trying to load the facebook JS API but need to wrap it in a require with a different context because I don't want the whole application to stop loading if Facebook is blocked by a firewall.

The problem I have is how to return the module from within the nested require() call.

My code looks something like this:

```
define( [ 'require' ], 
    function( require ) 
{
    var fbRequire = require( 
    { 
        context: 'fb',
        waitSeconds: 3
    } );

    fbRequire.onError = function()
    {
        console.warn( 'fbRequire.onError', arguments );
    };

    fbRequire( [ 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug.js' ], 
        function() 
    {
        console.log( 'facebook file now loaded' );

        // init the Facebook JS SDK
        var facebookSettings = {
            channelUrl: '//' + window.location.hostname + '/facebook-channel.html', // Channel File for x-domain communication
            status: true, 
            cookie: true, 
            xfbml: true,
            appId: '1234567890'
        };

        FB.init( facebookSettings );

        // this is the bit I'm confused about
        // how do I...
        return FB;
        // ...because it's asynchronous and needs to be returned from the define() call?
    } );
} );
```

This is a Dojo project, if that helps (do I need to use dojo/Deferred?).

Comment: Does making it a dependency not work?

Comment: That's how I originally wrote it but if Facebook is blocked the whole app falls over as the require throws an error and then won't load anything else. If Facebook isn't blocked it works fine that way. Using require() with a different context is apparently the answer. See: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/requirejs/go-RbejZ7Zg

Comment: Try to [catch the error](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#errbacks) and redefine Facebook to something local

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem but couldn't get the Dojo loader to not fallover when Facebook was blocked. Instead, I used straight JS to load the SDK. Hopefully this will help someone else.

```
define( [ 'require' ], 
    function( require ) 
    {
        return {
            /**
             * Loads a facebook asynchronously using require() and a "bang" (!).
             * 
             * @example require( ['my-project/facebookLoader!'],    function( facebook ) { ... } );
             */
            load: function( store, require, callback )
            {
                // already loaded?
                if( window.FB !== undefined )
                {
                    console.log( 'facebook already loaded - using global FB object.' );
                    callback( window.FB );
                }
                else
                {
                    require( [ 'dojo/dom-construct', 
                        'dojo/_base/window', 
                        'dojo/on',
                        'dojo/_base/event' ], // remove "/debug" in live env
                    function( domConstruct, win, on, event ) 
                    {
                        // add Facebook div
                        domConstruct.create( 'div', { id:'fb-root' }, win.body(), 'first' );

                        // init the Facebook JS SDK
                        var facebookSettings = {
                            channelUrl: '//' + window.location.hostname + '/facebook-channel.html', // Channel File for x-domain communication
                            status: false, // check the login status upon init?
                            cookie: true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
                            xfbml: false    // parse XFBML tags on this page?
                        };

                        // app ID from the App Dashboard
                        if( window.location.hostname == 'localhost' )
                        {
                            facebookSettings.appId = '123456788'; 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            facebookSettings.appId = '123456789'; 
                        }

                        // what do we do if Facebook is blocked or times out?
                        var loadFailed = function( errorEvent )
                        {
                            console.warn( 'Facebook failed to load. Some features will be unavailable. ' + ( errorEvent ? 'Script error.' : 'Timed out.' ) );

                            // scrap the timer (in case we got here from error event on script tag)
                            if( timerId )
                            {
                                window.clearTimeout( timerId );
                            }

                            if( errorEvent !== undefined )
                            {
                                event.stop( errorEvent );
                            }

                            window.fbAsyncInit = function(){}; // noop

                            // return fake Facebook object
                            callback( 
                            { 
                                getLoginStatus: function()
                                {
                                    return false;
                                }
                            } );

                        };

                        // give Facebook 5 seconds to load
                        var timerId = window.setTimeout( loadFailed, 5000 );

                        // hook into Facebook's load callback
                        window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
                        {
                            window.clearTimeout( timerId );
                            FB.init( facebookSettings );
                            callback(  window.FB );
                        };

                        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
                        ( function(d)
                        {
                            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
                            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug.js"; // dev version
                            //js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"; // production version
                            on( js, 'error', loadFailed );
                            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
                        }( document ) );

                    } );
                }
            }
        };
    } 
);
```